# Custom messageBox buttons in VC++

Tags: visual-c++

How can I create a  message box with buttons  named "A", "B", "C", instead of "Yes", "No", "Cancel" ? Do I have to make my own dialog, or can I do it with `MessageBox` or `MessageBoxEx` or something similar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First way is to create custom dialog for your needs. It is most common solution that will be worked exactly how you want.

Several ways with using hooks described there, see last one: [rsdn.ru](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/ui/custombox.xml). Note, that main article language is Russian, but samples of code are quite easy.

Another solution is to create timer with custom callback, then with using of FindWindowEx find messagebox, subclass it's window procedure and manipulate with controls.